# in python metpy.units not recognizing degC unit for temprature (calculatinh Heat Index)

Tags: heatmap, units-of-measurement, heat

i am calculating Heat Index (temprature, relative humidity) using python . showing error for units, thats why i am not able to calculate simple heat index

```
import pandas as pd
 from metpy.calc import heat_index
 from metpy import units

 wd = pd.read_csv(""D:/my data.csv")

 def calculate_heat_index(temprature, R_humidity):
     return heat_index(temprature \* units.degC, R_humidity \* units.percent)

 t = wd\['T2M_MAX'\]
 r = wd\['RH2M'\]

# calculate heat index

 wd\['HI'\] = calculate_heat_index(t, r)
 print(wd.head())
```

#my data structure

```
LON        LAT  YEAR  MM  ...  T2M_MIN  T2MDEW WS2M_MAX    RH2M
0  41.165321  82.919199  2002   1  ...   -19.74  -19.19     5.84   98.31
1  41.165321  82.919199  2002   1  ...   -19.67  -16.95     7.89  100.00
2  41.165321  82.919199  2002   1  ...   -13.06  -12.41     8.36   98.50
3  41.165321  82.919199  2002   1  ...   -11.19   -7.88    11.70   96.69
4  41.165321  82.919199  2002   1  ...    -7.26   -6.13    10.59   98.88
```

i want to add HI column in the same data and want to calculate Heat index for each row,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of your Units error is because of your import statement on line 3. It should be

```python
import pandas as pd 
from metpy.calc import heat_index
from metpy.units import units
```

There are two additional factors you'll need to take into account with your `calculate_heat_index` function after you import units:

1. You are passing in a `pd.Series` (essentially, a column from your data frame) as your `temperature` and `R_humidity` arguments, but the `heat_index` function you're calling in `metpy.calc` operates on `pint.Quantity` objects.
2. `heat_index` will return to you a `pint.Quantity`, not the `pd.Series` you are expecting to append onto your data frame as the new column 'HI'. Your .csv appears to want floating-point values, so you'll need to use `.magnitude` off of the returned quantity to strip it of its units.

There are a couple of ways to go about fixing this, either packing/un-packing the Series outside of calling your function and passing it individual temperatures and relative humidities, or putting that logic inside of the function so that it operates on whole `Series` at a time like this:

```python
def calculate_heat_index(temperatures, rel_humidities):
    result = pd.Series(index=temperatures.keys())
    for k in temperatures.keys():
        result[k] = heat_index(temperatures[k] * units.degC, 
            rel_humidities[k] * units.percent, True).magnitude
    return result
```

Renaming the parameters to be plural helps emphasize the point that these are `Series` of temperatures and relative humidities. Another good idea would be to use type annotations to reinforce that the function takes `Series` arguments and returns a `Series` result.

The last bool argument passed to `heat_index` controls whether the calculated heat index masks out the value (substituting NaN in the resulting Series) when the heat index calculation is not applicable for the given temperature. Passing **False** will prevent these NaN values from appearing for this reason, although whether that applies to your data set I can't tell because it excludes any max temperatures.

Answer (score 0):

```
thank you so much for reply
```

my final code is here,
import pandas as pd #to read csv
from metpy.calc import heat_index #calculating heat index
from metpy.units import units #define units
import numpy as np #showing data in array
wd = pd.read_csv("D:/NASA POWER/heat index/NASA-P weather data.csv")

```
def calculate_heat_index(temprature, R_humidity):
    return heat_index(temprature * units.degC, R_humidity * units.percent)

t = np.array(wd['T2M_MAX'])
r = np.array(wd['RH2M']) 

# calculate heat index
wd['HI'] = calculate_heat_index(t, r)
print(wd.head())
#wd.to_csv("HI.csv",index=False)
```